# how to extract cells from r dataframe and add as a new row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a following dataframe in r

```
Names        X_1          X_2          X_3           X_4
Name         Sagar II    Booster
Location     India       No            Discharge     Open
Depth        19.5        start         End
DOC          3.2         FPL           64 
Qunatity     234         SPL           50
```

Now I want to extract certain cells and their corresponding values in next cell. 
My desired dataframe would be

```
Names        Values
Name         Sagar II
Location     India 
Discharge    Open
Depth        19.5  
DOC          3.2 
FPL          64 
SPL          50
```

How can I do it in r?

Comment: Extraction names should exactly match the text in dataframe. `c(Name,Location,Discharge,Depth,DOC,FPL,SPL)`

Comment: So a given column could have both _key_ and _value_?

Comment: Given column will have `key` and column next to it will have `value` please refer to my desired dataframe

Comment: I understand that, but for example, 64 and 50 are values for FPL and SPL, whereas "Discharge" is a key which in the same column.

Comment: Yes. that can happen

Comment: what about the `"No"` value, how do we know we should remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from base R.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Names        X_1          X_2          X_3           X_4
Name         Sagar II    Booster
                 Location     India       No            Discharge     Open
                 Depth        19.5        start         End
                 DOC          3.2         FPL           64 
                 Qunatity     234         SPL           50",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

# A list of target keys
target_key <- c("Name", "Location", "Discharge", "Depth", "DOC", "FPL", "SPL")

# A function to extract value based on key and create a new data frame
extract_fun <- function(key, df = dt){
  Row <- which(apply(dt, 1, function(x) key %in% x))
  Col <- which(apply(dt, 2, function(x) key %in% x))
  df2 <- data.frame(Names = key, Values = df[Row, Col + 1],
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df2$Values <- as.character(df2$Values)
  return(df2)
}

# Apply the extract_fun
ext_list <- lapply(target_key, extract_fun)

# Combine all data frame
dt_final <- do.call(rbind, ext_list)

dt_final
      Names Values
1      Name  Sagar
2  Location  India
3 Discharge   Open
4     Depth   19.5
5       DOC    3.2
6       FPL     64
7       SPL     50
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient, but works for your example:

```
library(dplyr)

key_value = function(extraction){
  temp = matrix(NA, nrow = length(extraction), ncol = 2)
  temp[,1] = extraction

  for(ii in 1:nrow(temp)){
    index = df %>%
      as.matrix %>%
      {which(. == extraction[ii], arr.ind = TRUE)}

    temp[ii, 2] = index %>% {df[.[1], .[2]+1]}
  }

  return(data.frame(Names = temp[,1], Values = temp[,2]))
}
```

**Result:**

```
> vec = c("Name", "Location", "Discharge", "Depth", "DOC", "FPL", "SPL")

> key_value(vec)
      Names  Values
1      Name SagarII
2  Location   India
3 Discharge    Open
4     Depth    19.5
5       DOC     3.2
6       FPL      64
7       SPL      50
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "Names        X_1          X_2          X_3           X_4
                Name         SagarII    Booster   NA    NA
                Location     India       No            Discharge     Open
                Depth        19.5        start         End   NA
                DOC          3.2         FPL           64   NA
                Qunatity     234         SPL           50   NA", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```